getting JSON.parse error only while deploying it on vercel but works fine on localhost
This is working fine on localhost but i am facing error while deploying it to vercel

the errors i am getting


Just in case anyone else encounters this issue
In my case, doing a test with insomnia, I found that Vercel returned a page for authentication
I needed to go to project settings in vercel -> Deployment Protection -> Vercel Authentication -> disable
After saving and testing again with insomnia, it worked.

This did it for me. Thank you!
